# RFM69 Transmit and Receive

Tags: 8051

I'm using RFM69 for wireless communication. I'm new in wireless communication. How can I send data trough RL78 micro controller?

This is [the datasheet](http://www.hoperf.cn/upload/rf/RFM69-V1.3.pdf).

Comment: Hi hiren, and welcome to EEsx. In order to help us help you please add some informations about your problem: first of all add links to the datasheet so people don't need to search them on their own, then add something about what you did until now, what is your experience, or whatever you see fit. Your question as is is quite poor in my opinion, and might well be tagged as low quality and eventually even closed.

Comment: Do you understand SPI bus?

Answer (score 1):

Here is [the manufacturer's page for the RFM69](http://www.hoperf.com/rf/fsk_module/RFM69CW.htm).
It should tell you most of what there is to know about it.
(I see that that site is where you got the [RFM69 data sheet](http://www.hoperf.cn/upload/rf/RFM69-V1.3.pdf)  from).

From the datasheet, the following diagram on page 76 sows the general method ofs use.
You will usually need two of these.
Translating that into an 8051 based version should be easy enough as far as hardware goes.

[image]

Page 76, Fig 41

---

This block diagram from page 8 shows what happens inside the IC.

[image]

Comment: yes i have understand SPI protocol and also do work on them.

Comment: Thanks for schamatic of RFM69 but i want to know that how i should programme that should RFM69 transmit data and receive the data from another RFM69.  is any sample code for RFM69 from that i make my project.